# link vs button dilemma

Tags: html, button, markup

Can anyone shed some light to this situation: I have a link that opens in a modal, i add a link and a button that are set to go to the same url. If i click the link, the modal goes to the link, and shows the article properly. If i click the button, it shows the article embedded on the page.

Here's the url, click on newtest2

http://zaazoolive.thewebbusters.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=1&Itemid=2

Here's the code

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function change_url(){
     window.location.href="http://zaazoolive.thewebbusters.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1:newtest&catid=1:test&Itemid=2"
}
</script>
<a href="http://zaazoolive.thewebbusters.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1:newtest&catid=1:test&Itemid=2">next</a>
</head>

<body>

<button onclick="location.href='http://zaazoolive.thewebbusters.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1:newtest&catid=1:test&Itemid=2'">Next</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A workaround could be:

```
<a href="http://zaazoolive.thewebbusters.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1:newtest&catid=1:test&Itemid=2">
        <button></button>
</a>
```

**Edit:** Although it's working, is not a recommended code, as HTML spec clearly says that using  tag for  item is invalid, so treat this ONLY as a workaround.

P.S. Why are you using `<a></a>` in section head?

Comment: haha because I am a novice. This worked like a charm you rock. One question for you, behind the button, I can see a little line from the hyperlink, is it possible to not have that

Comment: try adding &nbsp; between <button></button> tags

Comment: This is invalid ... W3C specs says "The interactive element button must not appear as a descendant of the a element." and it will not validate ... Check :
http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/button.submit.html#button.submit-constraints

Comment: @Ahmad Alfy, you can always post your own solution

Comment: Dirty! Not only it gives you invalid code, but also it doesn't actually fix the problem, it only gives you a workaround. It's like fixing the airco of your car by taping a piece of plastic in your window, instead of just closing the window. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a apparent difference, being that the link calls `window.location`, while the button just sets `location`, but this is semantically the same.

That popup you got is created by JavaScript. So the link is just used for its url, but when you click it, a script gets executed that loads the content asynchronously and shows it in a popup.
This script does not affect the button (though it could). Find the script that does this and apply it to the button too.